# Pythronthreading Issues

Tags: python, multithreading

The Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

from threading import Thread
from time import *

print strftime("%Y.%m.%d - %H:%M:%S;\n", localtime())


def pruefeStatusAlarmUndBetrieb():
        sleep(3)
        print "Alarm und Betrieb"
        print strftime("%Y.%m.%d - %H:%M:%S;\n", localtime())



def pruefeStatusEingaenge():
    sleep(4)
    print "Eingänge"
    print strftime("%Y.%m.%d - %H:%M:%S;\n", localtime())



def pruefeStatusAusgaenge():
    sleep(6)
    print "Ausgänge"
    print strftime("%Y.%m.%d - %H:%M:%S;\n", localtime())



def pruefe():

    s = Thread(target=pruefeStatusAlarmUndBetrieb())
    s.start()

    t = Thread(target=pruefeStatusEingaenge())
    t.start()

    u = Thread(target=pruefeStatusAusgaenge())
    u.start()

pruefe()
```

what Python does:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7 /Users/????/Documents/smartsys/test/test_threading.py
2016.12.09 - 19:27:23;

Alarm und Betrieb
2016.12.09 - 19:27:26;

Eingänge
2016.12.09 - 19:27:30;

Ausgänge
2016.12.09 - 19:27:36;


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Sorry for all that german terms in it, hopefully it doesn't hinder anyone to understand that piece of code.

What i'm trying to solve:

I expect that code to run parallel, but its runing von after another thread, so its a serial operation, if a add an infinite loop with sleepcommand, execution will stay inside infinite loop, so the other threads will be still ignored.

What am i doing wrong, or have i missunderstood?

At the end all 3 threads should run parallel and do what ever i will supose them to do, after having slept a short period of thime.

Answer (score 3):

You must no call the target in `s = Thread(target=pruefeStatusAlarmUndBetrieb)`. Remove ().